# @iOSXCUITFindBy Annotations don’t work but the same code works when I use driver.findElement(By.xpath)

Tags: java, ios, appium

I automating iOS app on windows using Appium studio.
When I am using below its working fine, but when I am using pagefactory annotations.

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='UIAButton'][2]")).click();

 @iOSXCUITFindBy(xpath="//*[@class='UIAButton'][2]")
 MobileElement contactButton;
```

It is not able to find the xpath. how can I make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use xpath if you are using iOSXCUITFindBy because it is slow and could easily break. Use **accessibility, className, id, iOSClassChain, iOSNsPredicate or tagName** strategies instead.

Besides Xpath search does not work with the same expression in annotations, use a different xpath expression.

With a different strategy, I would do this:

```
@iOSXCUITFindBy(iOSClassChain = "**/XCUIElementTypeButton[2]")
MobileElement contactButton;
```